# I want to get results from my table ordered by on a column with value repeated most of the times on top. I am using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I want to get results from my table ordered by on a column with value repeated most of the times on top. I am using laravel

Data stored as

- Email            City
- abc@anc.com      Delhi
- abc@njd.com      Gurgaon
- bhy@jfl.com      Noida
- jsd@juk.com      Delhi
- hfk@jfj.com      Gurgaon
- jfs@jfk.com      Delhi

Expected Result

- Email City

  - abc@anc.com      Delhi
  - jsd@juk.com      Delhi
  - jfs@jfk.com      Delhi
  - abc@njd.com      Gurgaon
  - hfk@jfj.com      Gurgaon
  - bhy@jfl.com      Noida

Code I am using is

```
 $list = SubscriberList::select('subscriber_lists.*',DB::raw('COUNT(subscriber_lists.location) as locationCount'))
            ->where('status', config('constants.IS_NOT_ACTIVE'))
            ->orderBy('locationCount','DESC')
                ->paginate(config('constants.PAGE_LIMIT'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will surely solve your problem:

```
$result = DB::table('subscriber_lists')
                      ->select('email', 'city', DB::raw('count(*) as user_count'))
                      ->orderBy('city')
                      ->groupBy('email')
                      ->get();
          return $result->sortByDesc('user_count')->values();
```

You can also code like this using Model class:

```
$result = SubscriberList::select('email', 'city', DB::raw('count(*) as user_count'))
                      ->orderBy('city')
                      ->groupBy('email')
                      ->get();
          return $result->sortByDesc('user_count')->values();
```

Comment: Goto **config/database.php** and set  _'strict' => false_ , it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$list = SubscriberList::where('status', config('constants.IS_NOT_ACTIVE'))
    ->orderByRaw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscriber_lists sub WHERE city=subscriber_lists.city) DESC')
    ->paginate(config('constants.PAGE_LIMIT'));
```

Comment: i am getting location count in each element of object with value 6.

Comment: i just want to get the city which is repeated most of the time in column to be on top of my result.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my answer.